# Unable to write to Text File Exist in FTP server

Tags: java, file, ftp

I use below code to write to text file that exists in FTP server.but got  java.net.MalformedURLException

```
URL  url = new URL("ftp://p@g.com:g@1234@ftp.xyz.com/testjar/2014-03-06-p.txt;type=i");
      URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
      OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
      ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
      output.writeObject("hiiiii");
      buffer.close();
      os.close();
      output.close();
```

above username and password is not real but its demo that looks like real.
anybody know how to solve this issue or other method to write into a .txt file,let me inform.

Edit1:also my username and pass contains @ char and in pass number is there.
Full Error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "g@1234@ftp.xyz.com"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at CreateFolder.uploadfile(CreateFolder.java:39)
    at CreateFolder.main(CreateFolder.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "g@1234@ftp.xyz.com"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:217)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:614)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Did you read this "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/" and this "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide us with the error you get but I see couple of issues here:

1. Connection string: I know it's an example but if real user/pass contain '@' char, the URL won't be parsed.
2. `ObjectOutputStream` class is intended to write object data so it can be reconstructed by `ObjectInputStream` ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)). It's not for writing textual files. If all you need is writing String to stream better use [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

So the revised example will be:

```
try {
  URL  url = new URL("ftp://user:pass@ftp.xyz.com/testjar/2014-03-06-p.txt;type=i");
  URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
  OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
  OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
  PrintStream output = new PrintStream(buffer);
  output.print("hiiiii");

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {

  output.close();
  buffer.close();
  os.close();
}
```

Comment: yes you are write my username and pass both contain @ character.any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
replace '@' character with '%40' at parse time it will automatically got converted to '@'.

```
URL  url = new URL("ftp://p%40g.com:g%401234@ftp.xyz.com/testjar/2014-03-06-p.txt;type=i");
      URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
      OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
      PrintStream output = new PrintStream(buffer);
          output.print("wowhii");
      buffer.close();
      os.close();
      output.close();
```